Python code to get all the subclass objects of a given base class and call the function defined in the base class
Edit:
The question has been closed as duplicate to the Printing all instances of a class
However, there is are two differences here.

I want to create the object of all the subclass instances.
I can't modify the BaseClass to collect all the objects to a list. I need some mechanism to do this outside the BaseClass

Original question
I am new to python (coming from Java background) and experimenting a few things. One of them is to get all the subclasses (the subclasses of the subclasses as well) and call a function on that subclass object. The function is defined in the base class.
Python modules structure:

Code in base_class.py
class BaseClass:

    def __init__(self, entity_name):
        self.entity_name = entity_name
        
    def get_entity_name(self) -> str:
        return self.entity_name

Code in sub_classes.py
from test.sub_classes import SubClass1, SubClass2
from test.sub_classes_scanner import SubClassesScanner

sub_class_1 = SubClass1('SubClass_1_test')
sub_class_2 = SubClass2('SubClass_2_test')

print(sub_class_1.get_entity_name())
print(sub_class_2.entity_name)

all_subclasses = SubClassesScanner.get_all_existing_sub_classes()
for subclass in all_subclasses:
    print(subclass)
    try:
        print(subclass.get_entity_name())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    try:
        print(subclass.entity_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        

Code in sub_classes_scanner.py
from typing import Optional, Type, Set

from test.base_class import BaseClass
from test.sub_classes import SubClass1, SubClass2


class SubClassesScanner:
        
    @staticmethod
def get_all_existing_sub_classes(cls: Optional[Type[BaseClass]]=None,) -> Set[Type[BaseClass]]:

    if not cls:
        cls = BaseClass

    return set(cls.__subclasses__()).union(
        [
            s
            for c in cls.__subclasses__()
            for s in SubClassesScanner.get_all_existing_sub_classes(c)
        ]
)
    # return {SubClass1(), SubClass2()}

When I run the test_module.py code, I get the following output
<class 'test.sub_classes.SubClass1'> 

BaseClass.get_entity_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' 

type object 'SubClass1' has no attribute 'entity_name'        

<class 'test.sub_classes.SubClass2'> 

BaseClass.get_entity_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' 

type object 'SubClass2' has no attribute 'entity_name'

However, creating the object directly and invoking the function get_entity_name() works fine without errors (i.e., it prints the entity name passed as the parameter).
What should be done to make it work as intended? The goal is to scan all the subclasses (there could be as many as 100 subclasses) from different modules and packages dynamically (may tens of them typically) and invoke the function and get a response properly for each subclass.

What makes you think it is possible to call a method of an object for any class w/o said object?  How did you accomplish this in Java?

@ScottHunter, we have the object right? SubClassesScanner.get_all_existing_sub_classes() is giving the list of all the subclass objects isn't it? In Java, we use the concept of reflection. In spring boot, we have a concept of dependency injection. If we say @Autowired List<BaseClass> subclasses then all the classes extending BaseClass will be fetched and objects are created and will be populated in that list

@Ravi No. The variable sub_class_1 is not a subclass - it's an instance of the class SubClass1. The __subclasses__ method returns class objects, not instance objects, so it will never see any variables like sub_class_1.

@Ravi If you want all instances of a class, just add them to a list in the __init__ of the base-class. For example: class BaseClass: instances = []; def __init__(self): BaseClass.instances.append(self).

@ekhumoro, it makes sense now as to why I'm unable to call the functions. That's a good insights thanks. Is there a way to create an object from the instance of the class? I cannot modify the base class since it is from a 3rd party package. In java, we do it this way - BaseClass obj = Class.forName('FullNameOfTheSubclass').newInstance();

@Ravi Of course you can modify the third-party class: just create a subclass of it and use that as your base-class instead. Also, the accepted answer to question I linked to provides an alternative solution using gc.collect. I presume by "create an object from the instance of the class", you actually mean "create an instance from a class object". This is trivially solved by e.g. inst = cls(). In Python, literally everything is an object, including classes and functions.

@ekhumoro, thanks for the suggestions. While creating the subclass of the original class works for my custom classes, there are a few predefined classes that extend the original class and these cannot be modified since the library is using those classes directly. And gc.collect at least looks to be a costly operation as we are iterating over each and every object created (which also includes functions etc. as you mentioned). But, this is a good insight for me into Python programming

@Ravi Why do you need to collect all instances? That's a highly unusual requirement. What's the specific use-case?

@ekhumoro, i can you give you an example of a decorator pattern, where i want each decorator present and pass my object to each decorator and get the final result

@Ravi Please edit your question and provide a [mre].
